# Lookup for a concatanated string in multiple columns in a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a single user entry textbox for an address string i.e. it is not divided into block no., street address, city, state and zip. However my MySql table has individual columns for each of the address component. My task is to take the address string from the user and look it up against the address table and return id of the row that it matches with.

How do i do a reverse lookup for the whole string against these individual columns in  the address table? Also, it is not easy to parse the string because user can enter multiple spaces & street names can be tricky and can contains multiple words in them.

So to sum it up if user enters 123 South Main St Los Angeles CA 92032 then i should search against the address table with columns (address id, block no, street, city, state, zip) and return the address id.

Thanks,
Shakira

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from Address
where concat(street, city) like '%input%';
```

You would need full text searching setup, see
http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/
and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thanks Sachin that helps a lot, however it works better if i add empty space for concatenation e.g.  WHERE concat( blockno, ' ', streetname, ' '). However what i am looking for is a more full text search capability whereby if the user misses to enter city or state then too it should work. In the query that you recommended the user should enter the address in the correct sequence.

Comment: Okay. I see lot of questions related to full text search on right hand side, did you check them?
also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html if it helps.